# jar not created properly mvn relase

Tags: java, maven

I tried to create jar for a service A, which needs to be imported into service B.
when I ran the below command

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-DenvironmentName=<env>"
```

the jar got created but I am not able to import it into the service B. Error says "Cannot resolve symbol".

My guess is that the jar is not created properly, since it has these 3 folders:

- `BOOT-INF`
- `META-INF`
- `org.springframework.boot.loader`

when. my service name path is like `in.xyz.abc.commons`, there is no folder of this name in the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a JAR was created with the spring boot parent, it cannot be used as dependency.

So if A is a Spring boot service, it cannot be used in B.

Comment: "If a JAR was created with the spring boot parent" what does this mean. ? Yes the service A is a springboot service and service B is also springboot. How can I use the classes for service A in service B ?

Comment: You cannot. You need to build a library JAR that is not a Spring boot service. Then you can use this as dependency.

Comment: I created the jar only using this cmd:
mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-DenvironmentName=<env>"

Comment: You need to remove the Spring Boot parent.

Comment: okay, how to remove the spring boot parent ? are you suggesting to create a new service which will contain the exposed classes. I dont want to create a new service and move classes

Comment: The project A can either be a Spring Boot Service (having a `<parent>` entry in the `pom.xml` listing the Spring Boot parent), or it can be library that can be used by other services. It cannot be both.

Comment: So to make that clear: If you want to run A as a service, then the classes of A cannot be used by B.